# Renaming a slide name in Powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint

I am working in Powerpoint to build a clickable prototype. I have got around 50 slides and to link the pages, I am hyperlinking different slides with slide number.

Problem:
Once linking is done and I need to add some slides in the middle the slide numbers will get change and I will need to change the links again and again.

Is there any way so that I could change slide numbers with some slide names so that even if I need to add more slides in the middle of the presentation the link name remains the same?

For example can we make Link name - slide1 to link name aboutus?

Comment: Normally when you link from one slide to another then add new slides, PowerPoint deals with it for you.  Have you tested this and found that it doesn't work in your case?  If so, please describe exactly how you produced the links.

Comment: I was surprised to see it was working but not with all the slides. I added a new slide in the beginning and checked it. The links got updated and everything worked fine. But in some of the slides which were linked to slide 1 did not get change and pointed to the  new slide that was added.

Comment: There are a few reasons why links may cease to work or may work oddly. At one time, there was a limit to the amount of data allocated for link storage; if that amount was exceeded, newly added links would overwrite previous ones or fail to be added. Commas in slide titles can also cause problems.